# Create two dimensional boolean array from two other arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a two dimensional integer array and a two dimensional double array. If a value in the double array is less than the integer value at the same position of the two dimensional array, then in that part of the boolean array the value would is `true`. If it is greater, then the boolean would be `false`.

**How would I go about on this?**

This is what I tried so far:

```
public static boolean[][] CompareIntDouble(int[][] pizza, double[][] pasta) {
    boolean x = true;

    for (int hotdog=0; hotdog < pizza.length; hotdog++) {
        for (int toast=0; toast < pizza[hotdog].length; toast++) {
            pizza[hotdog][toast] = hotdog * 10 + toast;

            if (pasta[1][1] > pizza[1][1]) {
                x = true;
            } else {
                x = false;
            }

            if (pasta[1][2] > pizza[1][2]) {
                x = true;
            } else {
                x = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t72id.jpg)

Comment: did you try this yourself, if yes please show your code.

Comment: Updated the title to be more descriptive, modified the text to be more precise and have less typos and also copied the code from the picture into the question for easier reading and copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    int[][] t1 = new int[2][2];
    t1[0][0] = 0;
    t1[0][1] = 1;
    t1[1][0] = 2;
    t1[1][1] = 3;

    double[][] t2 = new double[2][2];
    t2[0][0] = 3;
    t2[0][1] = 2;
    t2[1][0] = 1;
    t2[1][1] = 0;

    boolean[][] f = new boolean[2][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (t1[i][j] > t2[i][j]) {
                f[i][j] = true;
            } else {
                f[i][j] = false;
            }
            System.out.println(i+" "+j+" :"+f[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

even tho you should try it by yourself first here you have a working example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 2d input arrays have the same size

```
    public static boolean[][] foo( int[][] a,double[][]b) {
    boolean[][] c = new boolean[a.length][a.length];

    for (int i=0;i<a[0].length ;i++ ) {
        for (int j=0;j<a.length ;j++ ) {
            c[i][j]= (a[i][j]>(int)b[i][j]);
        }
      }
    return c;
    }
```

Comment: maybe just some typos, but shouldn't `b[i][j]= (a[i][j]>Integer.parseInt(b[i][j]))` be `c[i][j]= (a[i][j]>Integer.parseInt(b[i][j]));`? also your code isn't working at all, because you cant use `Integer.parseInt` for double values

Comment: Now it should work fine, but you must always cast the double to an int before making a match. 
Also yes, there was a syntax error, thanks for pointing out.